# Implementation of a sidebar multilingual of a MDX file using Docusaurus

Tags: multilingual, sidebar, docusaurus

Is it possible to implement a multilingual sidebar menu of a MDX file using Docusaurus?
If it's possible can you please help me implement or show me some reference/samples.

I tried following their tutorials:
https://docusaurus.io/docs/i18n/git

Implement a multilingual sidebar menu.